# accessing large number of records in SOQL

Tags: salesforce

In salesforce, I am having a custom object and there can be million of records in that object in future. I am developing a dashboard using apex and visualforce so i need to access all the records at one time in single query.
 The query is: `[select count(custom_cases__C), status__c from custom_case__C group by status__c]`

So it is accessing all the records at one time and exceeding governer limits.

What can I do to achieve this?

please provide me with the solution and if possible with an example because I am new to salesforce.

Answer (score 3):

It is a shame that salesforce counts an aggregate function not as 1 result, but as the amount of rows aggregated. Which means that if you have over 50000 results, you'll get an error (SOBject query row exceeded, something in that line)

There is an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br7TAAS) for that, please upvote!

The only workable solution I see for you at the moment is (and also the solution I use myself) is program and schedule a [Apex Batch Job](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) to run, and save the results in a new custom object. Then use that custom object as the source for your dashboard.

Comment: I don't think that idea will ever get implemented. The 50000 results is a computational limit and it's almost the same problem to retrieve the records than to aggregate them.

Comment: Why do you want to store the records in another custom objects if he already has them stored in one object?? What difference would that make?

Comment: because you want the summarized data stored in another sobject, or in a field on a current object. But the problem is once you try to query over 50k records you will get an exception, regardless if you just query them for use in a list, or try to aggregate them. If you use batch jobs, you can get around limits.

Comment: I think he wants to show a report/dashboard. So if he uses a batch class he may not have the most recent results available, because you dont knoow when the batch class will be executed.

Comment: yes shailesh you are right. I want to display a dashboard that will read data from a custom object and after doing some calculation on the fetched data from that custom object I want to show that result on dashboard developed using VF page. I need to display 10-12 components on one page and for every component I need to query same object but with different queries and different aggregate function. So is there any solution like I fire my query only once on suppose say 1 million records and do some calculations for displaying various components.

Comment: If you are not performing any DMLs, then your best choice would be to run the page in readonly mode as suggested in my answer. Number of queries will depend upon from how many objects you wish to fetch the data and the relationship between those objects, but certainly the number of records you can work with by using readonly mode will be higher. By the way, your requirement seems to complicated, I doubt setting readonly mode will help you.

Comment: readonly mode has higher limits, but in the end you still have limits, whereas my suggestion is theoretically unlimited, only will you be working with data that potentially isn't up to date. Nevertheless upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

You can run your page in read only mode. There are certain restrictions on this also. You might want to take a look at the below link:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_readonly_context.htm